# How to check if PayPal subscription is still on trial period

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using `GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` endpoint of the PayPal classic API to retrieve information about the subscription. From the data, I get back from that endpoint, how do I determine if the customer is still on his initial trial period and not yet on the regular billing period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account is on trial, if `TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES > NUMCYCLESCOMPLETED`, that is, if you have completed less cycles that there are trial cycles.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with that API, but I think that if they are on trial you should be able to tell by looking at `PROFILESTARTDATE`. If it's in the future it should be on trial still.

Another option could be `NUMCYLESCOMPLETED`. I don't think a trial counts as a full cycle.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: `PROFILESTARTDATE` doesn't work as it is set to the beginning of the trial period, not to the end of trial period.